# FOSMessageBundle - Call to a member function getId() on null

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to implement the FOSMessageBundle, but whenever I try to access any message or non-empty messagelist (sent/received/deleted), I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null
```

which the stack shows as being generated by:

```
in vendor/friendsofsymfony/message-bundle/FOS/MessageBundle/Model/Message.php at line 160

public function getMetadataForParticipant(ParticipantInterface $participant)
{
    foreach ($this->metadata as $meta) {
        if ($meta->getParticipant()->getId() == $participant->getId()) {
            return $meta;
        }

    }
```

I'm at a loss why it cannot fetch the participant information. The data is correctly saved in the database and I have followed the installation instructions according to the documentation.

This my user entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Security;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueConstraint;
use FOS\MessageBundle\Model\ParticipantInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* User
*
* @ORM\Table("fos_user", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="UIDX_email_isArchived", columns={"is_archived", "email"})}))
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\Security\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements ParticipantInterface
{

//region Properties

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var GroupMember
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Security\GroupMember", mappedBy="member", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
 */
protected $groupMembers;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Security\Group")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_group",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $groups;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="displayName", type="string", length=512, nullable=true)
 */
private $displayName;

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_archived", type="boolean", options={"default" = "0"})
 */
private $isArchived;

//endregion

//region GettersAndSetters

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return GroupMember
 */
public function getGroupMembers()
{
    return $this->groupMembers->toArray();
}

/**
 * @param GroupMember $groupMembers
 */
public function setGroupMembers($groupMembers)
{
    $this->groupMembers = $groupMembers;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getDisplayName()
{
    return $this->displayName;
}

/**
 * @param string $displayName
 */
public function setDisplayName($displayName)
{
    $this->displayName = $displayName;
}

/**
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isIsArchived()
{
    return $this->isArchived;
}

/**
 * @param boolean $isArchived
 */
public function setIsArchived($isArchived)
{
    $this->isArchived = $isArchived;
}

//endregion

//region Methods

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->groupMembers = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->departments = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->pools = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->setIsArchived(false);
}

/* Override FOSUB */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    parent::setEmail($email);
    $this->username = $email;

    return $this;
}
public function setEmailCanonical($emailCanonical)
{
    parent::setEmailCanonical($emailCanonical);
    $this->usernameCanonical = $emailCanonical;

    return $this;
}

public function serialize()
{
    //return parent::serialize(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->email,
    ));
}

public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    //parent::unserialize($serialized); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->email,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
}


//endregion

}
```

my config.yml:

```
fos_message:
    db_driver: orm
    thread_class: AppBundle\Entity\Thread
    message_class: AppBundle\Entity\Message
```

The Message classes:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use FOS\MessageBundle\Entity\Message as BaseMessage;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Message extends BaseMessage
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *   targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Thread",
 *   inversedBy="messages"
 * )
 * @var \FOS\MessageBundle\Model\ThreadInterface
 */
protected $thread;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Security\User")
 * @var \FOS\MessageBundle\Model\ParticipantInterface
 */
protected $sender;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *   targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\MessageMetadata",
 *   mappedBy="message",
 *   cascade={"all"}
 * )
 * @var MessageMetadata[]|\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
protected $metadata;
}
```

Thread class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use FOS\MessageBundle\Entity\Thread as BaseThread;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Thread extends BaseThread
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Security\User")
 * @var \FOS\MessageBundle\Model\ParticipantInterface
 */
protected $createdBy;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *   targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Message",
 *   mappedBy="thread"
 * )
 * @var Message[]|\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
protected $messages;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *   targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ThreadMetadata",
 *   mappedBy="thread",
 *   cascade={"all"}
 * )
 * @var ThreadMetadata[]|\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
protected $metadata;
}
```